# get current index jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, fadein

hi i'm using a script made by
http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow
so basically the code i have now is

```
$(function(){
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
  $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
     .next('img').fadeIn()
     .end().appendTo('.fadein');
  }, 
  6000);

});
```

I wonder if it's possible to get the index of the current image that shows in anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this script works, it keeps moving the position of the DOM elements so that your current `img` is always index 0 and the next `img` is always index 1. If you want to know the  index out of your original order, you will need to store that data before the slideshow script runs:

```
$(function () {
   $(".fadein img").each(function (i, el) {
      $(el).data('index', i); // Store the index on the IMG
   });

   $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

   setInterval(function(){
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
      .next('img').fadeIn()
      .end().appendTo('.fadein');

      // Get the original index of the first img in the current show
      alert($('.fadein :first-child').data('index'));
   }, 6000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) for exactly that purpose.

Comment: yes but i tried $('.fadein img').index(); but that didnt work so how would i use it?

Comment: @Breezer: You should take a look at the documentation-link provided in meagars post.

Comment: Use `.next('img').index()` to get the index of the next img element.

Comment: I looked through the documentation and tried if i havent missed something pretty much everything when i try to alert the value out most of the times i get -1 or it outputs 0 for all the images

Comment: lets saay you would like to output the current index how would you approach this?

Comment: @Breezer The current index of what, and in what context? Are you looking for the last-appended image in the `.fadeIn` container? You can do that much more simply with `$('.fadeIn :last-child')`. Or, since it's likely the only visible image, you can do '$('.fadeIn img:visible')`.